# Where can pseudo-force be used?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames

I was doing this question

[image: enter link description here]

and eventually got the answer but I had a thought :-

It being a non inertial frame , can we apply pseudo force on it?

But as the question says both are travelling with same acc. . That's where I got stuck because I read somewhere that in addition to a non-inertial frame there has to be a relative motion between the bodies in order to apply pseudo force .

In addition to all of this I found a Sol. to the same problem in another book where there is no mention of a pseudo force but the FBD drawn has $ma$ as you can see . I assume it is pseudo force by judging the way the sol. was written .

[image: enter link description here]

This contradicts my above statement .

Now I am more confused than what I was before and now I do no not understand where pseudo force can actually be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It being a non inertial frame , can we apply pseudo force on it?

If you moved along with the system then you would need to do this. But nothing says we can't analyze an accelerating system from an inertial frame. In fact, this is typically what is done, especially in intro physics questions such as these.

> I read somewhere that in addition to a non-inertial frame there has to be a relative motion between the bodies in order to apply pseudo force .

This is incorrect. If you are in a non-inertial frame then pseudoforces will be present. That's all. (With your statement, single body systems would not experience pseudoforces).

> In addition to all of this I found a Sol. to the same problem in another book where there is no mention of a pseudo force...

Either they are doing what I mentioned at the beginning of this answer. Although the $ma$ term shouldn't be on the diagram if that's the case. Or $ma$ is the pseudoforce, which is what you would need to do if you moved with the system.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron i had one more doubt that if let a mass m is kept on a wedge  of mass M which is accelerating with a towards right. If we have to keep m stationary then we have to find range of acc. Now in this Q we will again use pseudo force but will pseudo force be applied in FBD of m along the surface of the wedge or directly opp. to a

Comment: @Kartik Think about your experience in a car accelerating forward. You get pushed into your seat, opposite the direction of the acceleration, right?

Comment: Right ,thanks @Aaron Stevens a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

So first let's summarize the topics in the problem:- 1) friction and it's limiting value 2) Newton's second law 3) Pseudo Force (not as such but let's see). The condition for relative slipping between two objects is that they should have a non zero magnitude of relative acceleration hence we have no slipping till $ a_{rel}=0 $ ( in this case all credits to @aleph zero for sporting the glitch ) now we know that if the slipping is not happening then friction has to be static in nature and hence we have an upper limit to our frictional force between the two blocks as $ μmg $ . So we need to find F such that frictional force reaches it's maximum value. So far I have not used Pseudo Force which now I will introduce. Let's dive into the frame of the lower block. With respect to it the upper block is at rest ( as there is no slipping) and as our frame is accelerated ( as the whole system of the two blocks  is moving on the smooth ground) we need to apply a Pseudo Force $ F=ma $ in the opposite direction to the acceleration of the frame and then we are allowed to apply Newton's laws in that frame and write the equilibrium equations using FBD as explained in fig.2  of your question. I hope my answer helped you please feel free if you want to suggest changes or ask more !

Comment: Thanks@Aditya I posted another doubt through comment in @Aaron's answer . Can you help me out with that

Comment: Yes surely i can help you .....notice that when you go in the wedge's frame you find that as the wedge is accelerating in the horizontally(as it is kept on horizontal fixed surface) you can assume that it has some non zero acceleration say $ A $ . While applying the Pseudo Force it acts horizontally on the smaller mass in the direction opposite to assumed direction of $ A $.

Comment: "The condition for relative slipping between two objects is that they should have a non zero magnitude of relative acceleration..." No, the condition is non zero relative *velocity*.  Objects can slip with a constant relative velocity (zero relative acceleration) if external forces are applied to them.

Comment: Now also notice that the explanation I provide here is just for frames that are linearly accelerated if we were given rotating coordinate systems and stuff we would need a more intricate mathematical analysis to understand

Comment: Thanks @Aditya you were great help

Comment: You are welcome mate( jee advance aspirants are always welcome )

Comment: @ alephzero in this case though the particles are constrained not to slip until they have different absolute accelerations in ground frame